# I want remove an object from array by splice() but not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, arraylist, array-splice

I have an `array`  that I want remove an **object** from this,
I try write this by `splice()`,
But when I found it and **splice** that, my code remove all objects Except object that found.

It's my JavaScript code:
[On jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a9b3fvky/)

```js
var MyArr = [{
    "id": "139",
    "count": 2,
  },
  {
    "id": "138",
    "count": 2,
  },
  {
    "id": "196",
    "count": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": "122",
    "count": 1,
  }
]

console.log(MyArr);
   var linkItemId = parent.find("a").attr("data-menu-id");
   var indexItem = MyArr.findIndex(x => x.id == linkItemId);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < MyArr.length; i++) {
        if (linkItemId == MyArr[i].id) {
            //var indexItem = arr[i].index;
            
            MyArr = MyArr.splice(indexItem,1);

            break;

        }

    }
```

Comment: [`.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) modifies the array in place and **returns the removed elements**. Just don't assign it's return value to `MyArr`

Comment: If you're going to change the code of your question _after_ someone already added an answer for the old version at least notify them about that change. But that modification of yours shouldn't be necessary in the first place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

- You have to specify the `deleteCount` to be 1.
- The return value of `splice` is the deleted element(s) (not to re-assign to `MrArr`)

```
MyArr.splice(indexItem, 1);
```

Comment: You should write `MyArr.splice(indexItem, 1);` instead of `MyArr = MyArr.splice(indexItem,1);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findIndex()` for finding the removable item from the array then apply the splice.

```js
var MyArr=[{id:"139",count:2,bgColor:"rgb(104, 213, 247)",link:"/inv/invmonitoringexpertgroupraghabehplanresult/index",icon:"atis-icon icon-bizPlan",name:"بررسی طرح های اقتصادی",sysname:"طرحهای اقتصادی"},{id:"138",count:2,bgColor:"rgb(104, 213, 247)",link:"/inv/invmonitoringexpertgroup/index",icon:"atis-icon icon-bizPlan",name:"کارشناسان نظارت بر طرح های اقتصادی",sysname:"طرحهای اقتصادی"},{id:"196",count:1,bgColor:"rgb(153, 132, 255)",link:"/rnt/rntrequestevaluation/report",icon:"atis-icon icon-rent",name:"گزارش کارشناسی ها",sysname:"عملیات اجارات"},{id:"122",count:1,bgColor:"rgb(218, 111, 227)",link:"/cnt/cntplan/index",icon:"atis-icon icon-contract",name:"تعریف طرح",sysname:"سرمایه گذاری و اطلاعات قراردادها"}];

const itemIndex = MyArr.findIndex(item => item.id === '139');
if (itemIndex > -1) {
  MyArr.splice(itemIndex, 1)
}

console.log(MyArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

You can also remove the item using the `Array.prototype.filter()` method. The filter will return a new array without modifying the original `MyArr`.

```
const result = MyArr.filter(item => item.id !== '139');
```

The `result` array is containing all the items except the item with id `139`.

Comment: I update my question. I wrote this code before I write question here. but it's not work and remove all expect one! please check out again my code.

Comment: The `Array.prototype.splice()` remove items from an array and returns the deleted items. In your code when you write `MyArr = MyArr.splice(index, 1)` there the `MyArr` is replaced by the deleted item's array.